# Show that the sum of the series is $ \frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(1-m) }{\Gamma (n-m+2)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that  the series

$ \frac{1}{n+1} + m. \frac{1}{n+2}+ \frac{m (m+1)}{2!}\frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{m(m+1)(m+3)}{3!}.\frac{1}{n+4} + ............ = \frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(1-m)}{\Gamma(n-m+2)}$

where $-1 < n <1$

I know that

$\frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(1-m)}{\Gamma(n-m+2)} =\beta(n+1, 1-m) = \int_0^1 x^{n}(1-x)^{-m-1} dx $

Please tell me how to proceed further. Thank You

Comment: How do the $m$-factors evolve? You say $1, m, m(m+1), m(m+1)(m+3)$ divided by increasing factorials, and then assume that the rest is obvious. Am I missing something? Also, the $m$ factors seen to be increasing, while the $n$ factors are comparable to the harmonic series, so to me it doesn't look like it's converging at all.

Comment: @Arthur: $m(m+1)(m+3)$ appears to be a typo for $m(m+1)(m+2)$: the typical term is $\binom{m+k-1}k\cdot\frac1{n+k+1}$.

Comment: You should add that $m$ is not a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$B(n+1,1-m) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{i+m-1\choose i}{n+i+1}$$

Comment: @ Fry : Please explain how would come

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the following Taylor series in the integral
$$ (1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}x^k $$
where
$$ \binom{\alpha}{k}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!} $$